# Unable click on Toogle button ,Web View,Picker using robotium

Tags: android

I create an .apk file but i can not handle these four buttons.Please give me suggestions.

Comment: clear your question. Nobody understand by single line

Comment: i unable to handle switch button and datepicker in robotium.There is no any method for switch button in robotium and when i call setdatepicker method (basis of index) then junit test failed.

Answer (score 0):

Robotium does not support web view.
You have to use clickontext  method for switch button and date picker

Comment: Does not work clickontext() for switch button or date picker.In switch button it not give any exception but does not work . but in datepicker it give error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet

View switch = (View) solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewByID(R.id.switchid);
solo.clickOnView(switch);